# Supercars for Breakfast achievement

Tags: achievements, need-for-speed-payback

I am working on this achievement in Need for Speed Payback.

[image: Supercars for breakfast]

> Beat all the members of the 1% Club roaming racers league in the
>   Nissan GT-R

However I have already beaten a few of these roaming racers in other vehicles.

I have now bought a Nissan GTR. Will I need to beat the same roaming racers again in order to unlock this achievement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to beat the same drivers again in the GTR in order to get the achievement.

Every single driver of the Club needs to be beaten with the GTR, the achievement doesn't progress unless a race against these drivers is

- a win
- in the GTR

[Here's a link](http://www.powerpyx.com/need-for-speed-payback-all-roaming-racer-locations/) to each of their locations in-game, along with instructions to start each encounter.